# Javascript animate Method Accumulation Problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to do an animation example but there is a problem about accumulation. At first click on the button, the translate animation is done and the position of the element changes permanently. However, on second click it does the translate animation again but this time does not keep the last position. How to overcome this? I went through MDN document and applied the optional section but failed to complete this challenge. Regards,

https://jsfiddle.net/ja218pbr/19/

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].animate([
  {transform: 'translate(100%, 0)'}
    ], {
    duration: 250,
    composite: "accumulate",
    iterationComposite: "accumulate",
    fill: "forwards"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to be able to let the object slide again from the position it ended in earlier. To do this we can get the boundingClientRect each time the button is clicked and calculate the new translation distance by basically taking the width of the object and adding the left distance of the client rect, this will effectively allow the rectangle to keep moving from the distance it ended in before. Also I removed the `composite` property because it caused the rectangle to jump over the correct position.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  const clientRect = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const translationX = clientRect.width + clientRect.left;
  document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].animate([{
    transform: `translate(${translationX}px, 0)`
  }], {
    duration: 250,
    iterationComposite: "accumulate",
    fill: "forwards"
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>Moving Object</div>
<button>Press</button>
```